# Why listening to the thingsboard stream continues even though we unsubscribe the subcription?

Tags: flutter, stream, listener, subscription, thingsboard

I write my code similar web socket API example of below link:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/dart-client/

In my code,  I provided a command to get telemetries of the period of time and store them in fix size array, after that, I got the latest telemetry every 60 seconds and I added that telemetry to my array. My app works well until the internet connection is good. when the internet disconnected, I saw  'WebSocket Error: error code - 1002'  in the console of Android studio, in this situation getting telemetries for a period of time, is done again! this caused to overflow of my array!

```
    // Create subscription command with entities query and timeseries subscription
    var cmd = EntityDataCmd(query: devicesQuery, tsCmd: tsCmd);

    // Create subscription with provided subscription command
    var telemetryService = tbClient.getTelemetryService();
    var subscription = TelemetrySubscriber(telemetryService, [cmd]);

    // Create listener to get data updates from WebSocket
    subscription.entityDataStream.listen((entityDataUpdate) {
      print('Received entity data update: $entityDataUpdate');
    });
    // Perform subscribe (send subscription command via WebSocket API and listen for responses)
    subscription.subscribe();

    // Wait few seconds to show data updates are received by subscription listener
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    // Finally unsubscribe to release subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe();
```

I checked my code, I understand that listening to the stream continued even though I write `subscription.unsubscribe();` after fetching telemetries of period time!
how I could stop listening to Stream?